# How to create a separate routing for a module in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-navigation, cubit

I have two pages: **ConversationsListScreen** (it displays list of conversations) and **ConversationScreen** (shows a particular conversation, user gets in here from ConversationsListScreen).

These two pages should be wrapped into a separate module because they both are needed the same data (that I'd like to provide via common cubit class). So that I've created a **MessagesModule**.

```
    class MessagesModule extends StatelessWidget {
      final String _currentUserId;
      final String _currentLocale;
    
      const MessagesModule({
        @required String currentUserId,
        @required String currentLocale,
      })  : _currentUserId = currentUserId,
            _currentLocale = currentLocale;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocProvider<MessagesModuleCubit>(
          create: (context) => MessagesModuleCubit(_currentUserId, _currentLocale),
          child: ConversationsListScreen(),
        );
      }
    }
```

After redirection to **ConversationScreen** it opens on the same level as **MessagesModule**, it means that my context doesn't contain **MessagesModuleCubit**. But I'd like to see **ConversationScreen** nested to **MessagesModule**, the same as **ConversationsListScreen**. [Here is a current structure of my widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq99Q.png)

How can I manage routing for these two pages so that I can use their common state from MessagesModuleCubit?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the provider to your main file so it wraps both of the widgets in any case